# Get Android Market InApp Billing Product Lists

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-billing

Is there a way (maybe undocumented) to request my Android Market InApp Billing Product List (listing name,description and value of my items) via the In-app Billing Service API? I checked the available In-app billing requests (http://developer.android.com/guide/market/billing/billing_overview.html) and there is no request for such basic task.

Comment: Have you found a way to get all products ?

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no built-in opportunity. You should manually list the products within their product ids.